# Network monitoring tool for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, monitoring

I am using my ubuntu system as an internet gateway.

I am searching for a Network monitoring tool (Web based or command
line based) with which I can see which computers from my network are communicating which domains and IP address on the internet

Also, if I can find out the top domains or IP to/from which data is sent or received from.

The thing is some system from my network is throwing bruteforce attacks and spamming outwards. I want to know exactly which system is sending out data and is causing problems to me.

All help, advices would be appreciated !
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would begin with some basic, well documented, time tested tools.

https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

Answer (score 1):

A quick method of analyzing traffic would be to use a packet analysis platform such as [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or even [Wireshark/`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/).

However, if you're looking to specifically identify or prevent malicious traffic, you probably want to look into a fully-fledged Intrusion Detection System (IDS). [`snort`](https://www.snort.org/documents) is one of the most robust today, and can even run on the Ubuntu system if wanted (but I wouldn't recommend).